# Return value of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I'm doing a Java practice which told me to write a toString method, but I'm stuck with the return value of ArrayList. For more instruction, please read the comment of the toString part.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Student {
    /** The student's name */
    private String name;
    /** Course codes which the student is enrolled in */
    private ArrayList<String> courses;

    /** Creates a new student with the given name.
     * @name the student's name
     */
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.courses = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /** Enrol in a course.
     * @param course course code of the course being enrolled in. e.g. CSSE2002
     */
    public void addCourse(String course) {
        this.courses.add(course);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the human-readable string representation of this student.
     * The format of the string to return is
     * "'name': courses='courseCodes'" without the single quotes,
     * where 'name' is this student's name and 'courseCodes' is a comma-separated
     * list of this student's enrolled courses.
     * For example, if the student is enrolled several courses:
     * "John Smith: courses=CSSE2002,DECO3801".
     * If the student is enrolled in one course: "John Smith: courses=CSSE2002".
     * If the student is not enrolled in any courses: "John Smith: courses=NO_COURSES".
     * @return string representation of this student
     */
    public String toString() {
        
        Boolean CheckArray = courses.isEmpty();
        if(CheckArray == true){
            return this.name + ":" + " courses=NO_COURSES";
        }else{
            return this.name + ":" + " courses=" + this.courses;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I keep having this error on my test cases when running the program, [image]

I don't know how to get ride of the extra [], it seems like a silly question and would be nice if someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the tests?

Comment: That are the tests autogenerated from the system. I don't have test cases by my own

Comment: The test output might be misleading because it contains extra `[]`. I think your string output includes `[]` around the courses and it is supposed to not contain any `[]`.

Comment: @khelwood Yeah I was confused by that at first, which is why I asked for the tests. But then I saw the comments above `toString`, which specifies what kind of output is expected.

Comment: Side notes: There is no reasons to use `Boolean` type inside `toString()`, use `boolean` instead. It's different types and `ArrayList::isEmpty()`  return latter. Checks like `CheckArray == true` is meaningless as the result of this expression is boolean and `CheckArray` already of type boolean. So you can just write `if (CheckArray)`. Last but not least, by convention Java use `camelCase` for local variable names, so it is better to change `CheckArray` to `checkArray`.

Comment: What's the difference of `Boolean` and `boolean`, as both works with the code.

Comment: @khelwood - Yes, that is correct.  The test output is using square brackets to highlight the differences between the expected and actual strings.  This is standard behavior for JUnit tests .... IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the code comments, The test cases seem to expect an output such as:

```
John Smith: courses=CSSE2002,DECO3801
```

You can use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) to join the course codes with the delimiter `,`:

```
return this.name + ":" + " courses=" + String.join(",", this.courses);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to format the output of `this.courses` by replacing the brackets with an empty String.

```
return this.name + ":" + " courses=" + Arrays.toString(this.courses).replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```